# Android how to enable/disable auto sync programmatically

Tags: android, synchronization

I need to know how to toggle auto sync on and off programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [enable/disable auto sync programmatically!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138026/enable-disable-auto-sync-programmatically)

Comment: that one is [closed] and from the same person

Answer (score 23):

I think you are looking for

```
ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(<boolean>);
```

What docs says:

> Sets the master auto-sync setting that applies to all the providers
>   and accounts. If this is false then the per-provider auto-sync setting
>   is ignored.
>
> This method requires the caller to hold the permission
>   WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS.

So don't forget to add permission into manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

This should disable / enable all the syncs.

---

@Sajmon: I updated this i think very useful answer (i'm using this in my personal project).

Comment: +1 I edited and updated your answer. Now i think that thing is clearer.

Comment: Is it possible to do it from ADB??

Comment: To be able to implement a toggle you also need READ_SYNC_SETTINGS.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is the following:

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true/false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Code for **Sync Accounts** Programmatically:

**Sync once:**

```
public static void syncAllAccounts(Context contextAct) throws Exception {
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(contextAct);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    String accountName = "";
    String accountType = "";
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        accountName = account.name;
        accountType = account.type;
        break;
    }

    Account a = new Account(accountName, accountType);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(a, "com.android.calendar", new Bundle());
}
```

**Sync on time interval automatically:**

```
public static void syncAllAccountsPeriodically(Context contextAct, long seconds) throws Exception {
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(contextAct);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    String accountName = "";
    String accountType = "";
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        accountName = account.name;
        accountType = account.type;
        break;
    }

    Account a = new Account(accountName, accountType);
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(a, "com.android.calendar", new Bundle(), seconds*1000);
}
```

If you want to **sync** accounts **once**, call **first** method and if you want to **sync** on **some time of interval** you have to call **second** method and pass **seconds** (Like 10 Seconds) as **arguments** in it.

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

Ben is correct.

You need to use

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true/false);
```

you will also need to add permission "WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the user to disable sync through settings screen,So that sync will always perform