# How can I enable the sync option by default when false in app?

Tags: android, odoo, odoo-8, android-syncadapter, odoo-mobile

I use [odoo mobile framework](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework). How can I enable the sync option on app startup? (The option is disabled by default.)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838939/2700586

Comment: @Mani Thanks for your reply, But I already tried it, Not works for me!

Comment: Consider looking at [OdooJsonRpcClient](https://github.com/kasim1011/OdooJsonRpcClient) for Android.

Answer (score 1):

[odoo](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework) has a [customer_sync_adapter.xml](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/customer_sync_adapter.xml) and a [CustomersSyncProvider.java](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/addons/customers/providers/CustomersSyncProvider.java); when looking at the referenced [ResPartner.java](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/base/addons/res/ResPartner.java), it says that, `String AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".core.provider.content.sync.res_partner";`. An `Account` of type `com.odoo.auth` is expected, while assigning the proper content authority is important, else it will resolve nothing.

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ResPartner.AUTHORITY, true);
```

for the other one `sync-adapter`, the respective `contentAuthority` & `accountType` are required.

would only enable it on first run, or just ask the user. when always enabling it, it is difficult to disable it.