# Receiving mail in a IntentService

Tags: android, email

How to check for e-mails from an IntentService on an Android device?
Is there any library?
I googled a lot for this, but i can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no system API to check for email.

Email is handled by an individual app, which can be GMail, K-9 Mail, built-in email app etc.

None of them allow to read emails programmatically, because this would be a huge security hole.

The only two things you can do is to show 'New mail' dialog in Gmail with pre-filled text and address, and force account sync, which should force GMail to check for new mail immediately: [Android how to enable/disable auto sync programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138256/android-how-to-enable-disable-auto-sync-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution: javaee.github.io/javamail/#JavaMail_for_Android